# should allow 100 update/create per day per user using ASP.NET C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a requirement where i need to limit the number of request(to call webservice) Per user like 100 updates or creates per day per each user. So, I have written some C# code using Cache to do that job but it's failing since i am not getting each and every user count. it's just limiting the updates to 100 per day for all the users. Could you please help me with it below is the code that i have written. Now i need to get each user id and each user operation count(whether he updated anything).

```
String Id = request.UserCode + "" + "Synchronize";
System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
var _Limitcount = 100;

string key = Id;
SynchronizeProposalRequestOutput sPRO = null;
if (cache[key] == null)
{
    sPRO= ProposalServiceControl.SynchronizeProposal(request);( operation for update)
    cache.Set(key, count, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), null);
    count++;

}
else if (cache[key] != null && count > _Limitcount)
{
    PrimaLog.Error(request.UserCode + " Proposal synchronization failed user reached the number of limits");
    throw new Exception("You have reached the Maximum number of Proposal updates per today");

}
else if (cache[key] != null && count <= _Limitcount)
{
    sPRO = ProposalServiceControl.SynchronizeProposal(request);
       
    count++;
    cache.Set(key, count, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), null);
}
//3 execution
return sPRO;
```

Comment: Where is your count variable set? It looks like that’s not associated with any user or cache?

Comment: Have you verified that `request.UserCode` is set properly?

Comment: Plus, seeing the class `request` is an instance of would be helpful

Comment: Hi ,yes in the request.UserCode i am getting the id of the User for each user it will be unique so in the line  String Id = request.UserCode + "" + "Synchronize";   i am getting the Id as  ""A1234synchronize"" -@PaulKertscher

Comment: when the first request comes it is checking the first if condition at that time the cache[key] field is null so it will go inside the if condition and update the report and sets the count in the cache to 1.when a different user logs in the cache key has to be null again but in my case it is not null it's still showing my id and it will goes to last else if condition and just incrementing the count so here the problem is i wanna add all the users to the cache and set each user count to it particular user id  how to add the list of users to cache and maintain the each user count  -@PaulKertscher

Comment: when the first request comes it is checking the first if condition at that time the cache[key] field is null so it will go inside the if condition and update the report and sets the count in the cache to 1.when a different user logs in the cache key has to be null again but in my case it is not null it's still showing my id and it will goes to last else if condition and just incrementing the count so here the problem z i wanna add all the users to the cache and set each user count to it particular user id how to add the list of users to cache and maintain the each user count -@scottdavidwalker

Answer (score 0):

```
 string Id = request.UserCode + "" + "Synchronize";
 System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
 var _Limitcount = LimitProposalNumber;
 string key = Id;
 if (cache[key] == null)
  {
   sPRO = ProposalStorageServiceController.SynchronizeProposal(request);
   int count = 0;
   cache.Set(key, ++count, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), null);
  }
  else
  {
   int currentUserCount = (int)cache.Get(key);
   if (currentUserCount <= _Limitcount)
       {
  sPRO = ProposalStorageServiceController.SynchronizeProposal(request);
                    cache.Set(key, ++currentUserCount, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    PrimaLog.Error(request.UserCode + " Proposal synchronization failed user reached the number of limits");
                    throw new Exception("You have reached the Maximum number of Proposal updates per today");
                }
            }
            //3 execution
            return sPRO;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).